# Expectation of product of two random variables.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process, levy-processes

If I have a compound possion process due to which I can generate a poison random measure $N$ then I can write my compound poisson process in the another form as
$$\sum_{i=1}^{P_t}Y_i  = \int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,t]}zN(dz,ds).$$ Where $P_t$ is the poison process with intensity $\lambda$ and $Y_i$ are i.i.d jump sizes. If there is brownian motion $W$ independent of the jump sizes $Y_i$, and poisson process $P_t$ then what will be
$$\mathbb{E}\Big[\exp\Big(\int_0^tf(s)dW(s)+ \int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,t]}g(s,z)N(dz,ds)\Big) \Big] =\mathbb{E}\Big[\exp\Big(\int_0^tf(s)dW(s)\Big)\exp\Big( \int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,t]}g(s,z)N(dz,ds)\Big) \Big] =? $$ where $f,g$ are deterministic continuous functions.

Can we just write it as a product of the expectation of two components or not? Some explanation or a proof would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: You could separate the expectations. Because the Poisson random measure and the Brownian motion are independent, the integrals over the Poisson measure and Brownian motion are also independent as are the exponentials of the integrals. I don't have time now, but I'll try to see how much that can be simplified and write it up in a few days.

Comment: @forgottenarrow Thanks for above :)  I speculated that (as is kind of intuitive due to independence). I appreciate your help and would be grateful if you could provide some extra help in the form of explanation or proof. Thanks :)

Comment: The simple version is that we know if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $f$ and $g$ are real-valued, measurable and integrable functions, then $E[f(X)g(Y)] = E[f(X)]E[g(Y)]$. A stochastic integral of a deterministic function (assuming you have enough regularity, and I think continuous should suffice) is a measurable function of the driving noise (the Brownian motion and the Poisson process in this case). All I would be doing in a rigorous proof is showing these two facts are true.